# Cross account replication of S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have successfully configured cross account replication of S3 bucket objects. On the source bucket side I can easily specify the prefix and only objects with those prefix are getting replicated.
I followed [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html)

I even modified the policy/permissions on the dest bucket account and things are working fine.

However, I am unsure what do I have to do in order to specify that the objects when getting replicated must be replicated to a destination prefix of my choice or under a prefix. How do I achieve that?

For example on the console on the source bucket side where I say cross account, it won't let me specify the prefix there.

Answer (score 1):

[Replicating objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) using Same-Region / Cross-Region Replication **cannot replicate** to a different destination path/prefix.

You would use a different mechanism to perform the replication, or perhaps create an AWS Lambda function in the other account that 'moves' the objects after they have been created.

Comment: I am trying to find on the link you pointed if it explicitly states this limitation. Pardon me if I missed it but I dont see it explicitly written though at the same time I could not find a way to configure the prefix either on the destination side that gets the replicated object

Comment: It is not explicitly written. It is simply not available for configuration.